# web: How can I place an input box in a picture?

Tags: html, webforms, input

I want to use a picture as my website design. It's a plain one, like google's.

```
<img src... done... >
```

now, I want to place an input box at the text area of the picture, how to I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach IMHO would be to have a `<div>` with that image as a background and one `<input>` child positioned using margins, or absolute positioning, like this:

```
<div style="background: url(img/background.jpg) no-repeat;">
  <input type="text" name="whatever" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 40px;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not necessarily a good design.

To implement it, you need to use CSS.

You should make a large container `<div>` and apply the following rules:

```
div.Container {
    background: url('image');
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
div.Container input#MyTextBox {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 150px;
}
```